# Some websites bypass hosts file in Safari

Tags: macos, mac, hosts-file

I downloaded a hosts file from a Github which lists all porn websites, in order to block them on my computer.
This works well with Chrome, unfortunately on Safari *some* websites are not blocked at all.

For example xhamster.com is *not* blocked while pornhub.com is.

I have tried everything mentionned in the threads [OSX Sierra hosts file is ignored](https://superuser.com/questions/1191172/osx-sierra-hosts-file-is-ignored) and other similar ones, to no avail (flushing cache, tabs instead of spaces, IPV4 and IPV6 etc.)
I also tried recreating a hosts file with just this domain and it does not work.
I am on Big Sur with Safari 14.1.1

Can someone else at least try to reproduce this bug?
What other solutions do I have?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you actually try _both_ IPv4 and IPv6 entries for the same domain?

Answer (score 11):

An answer on Stack Overflow
[Why does /etc/hosts not work anymore for some websites on Big Sur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972371/why-does-etc-hosts-not-work-anymore-for-some-websites-on-big-sur)
(unfortunately closed)
gives as answer a new DNS feature added in order
to speed up access to sites that support HTTPS,
but which unfortunately may workaround the `hosts` file.

I quote the answer here:

> macOS 11 added support for what is officially called [“Service binding
> and parameter specification via the DNS (DNS SVCB and
> HTTPSSV)”](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnsop-svcb-httpssvc).
>
> Now, when you visit a website, it’s not just the typical DNS `A`
> host-to-ip-address record that’s consulted, but a brand-new `HTTPS`
> DNS record is checked too. It’s not just a name entry; it’s a
> brand-new record type
> ([#65](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml)),
> to go along with the more familiar `A` and `CNAME` and `MX`.
>
> These new `HTTPS` DNS records can indicate that the site supports
> HTTPS, including protocol versions and IP addresses. That way, typing
> in a bare domain name gives the `https://` version of the site right
> away, maybe even on HTTP/2 or HTTP/3, skipping the old-fashioned HTTP
> redirect. There’s even a [draft
> option](https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049713451-DNS-Resolver-Selection-in-iOS-14-and-macOS-11)
> for domain operators to tell your computer to bypass any local DNS
> settings and use a specific server for all future DNS queries
> involving their domain.
>
> There are many pro-performance intentions here, and some pro-privacy
> ones too.
>
> But there is a fatal privacy and security flaw in both the
> specification and implementation: **it removes the ability for users
> to override domain name lookups in `/etc/hosts`, even when faced with
> actively malicious domain name operators**.
>
> To see how this is working in action:
>
> - The version of `dig` that comes with macOS doesn’t directly support these new records, but you can see whether they exist with
>
>   ```
>   $ dig -t type65 www.politico.com
>   …
>   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>   ;www.politico.com.        IN  TYPE65
>
>   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>   www.politico.com. 53806   IN  CNAME   www.politico.com.cdn.cloudflare.net.
>   www.politico.com.cdn.cloudflare.net. 300 IN TYPE65 \# 58 0001000001000302683200040008681210CA681211CA000600202606
>   ```
>
> 47000000000000000000681210CA2606470000000000000000006812 11CA
> …
>
> - I don’t know how to parse that, but wireshark does if I packet-capture it
>
>   ```
>   Domain Name System (response)
>       Queries
>           www.politico.com.cdn.cloudflare.net: type HTTPS, class IN
>       Answers
>           www.politico.com.cdn.cloudflare.net: type HTTPS, class IN
>               Name: www.politico.com.cdn.cloudflare.net
>               Type: HTTPS (HTTPS Specific Service Endpoints) (65)
>               Class: IN (0x0001)
>               Time to live: 300 (5 minutes)
>               Data length: 58
>               SvcPriority: 1
>               TargetName: <Root>
>               SvcParams
>                   SvcParam: ALPN
>                       SvcParamKey: ALPN (1)
>                       SvcParamValue length: 3
>                       ALPN length: 2
>                       ALPN: h2
>                   SvcParam: IPv4 Hint
>                       SvcParamKey: IPv4 Hint (4)
>                       SvcParamValue length: 8
>                       IP: 104.18.16.202
>                       IP: 104.18.17.202
>                   SvcParam: IPv6 Hint
>                       SvcParamKey: IPv6 Hint (6)
>                       SvcParamValue length: 32
>                       IP: 2606:4700::6812:10ca
>                       IP: 2606:4700::6812:11ca
>   ```
>
> So that’s what’s happening:
>
> 1. Safari on Big Sur can load some websites you’ve blocked in `/etc/hosts`, because it gets their IP addresses from these new
>    `HTTPS` records
> 2. It can only do that for some sites, because most domain name operators haven’t set this up yet. It looks like Cloudflare has done
>    this for everyone on their platform; fortunately most domain name
>    operators, including the advertising/tracking/malware giants, haven’t
>    caught on to this yet.
>
> For now, you can keep using `/etc/hosts` for domain names that you
> fully control.
>
> In the meantime, for other domains, you have some options:
>
> - you could run a local DNS server or firewall on your home network that [blocks these
>   requests](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/local-dns-resolves-first-time-but-not-after-ios-only/41305/39)
> - you could configure a local DNS resolver daemon on your mac, and use it to  block these requests
> - you could switch to a Linux distribution where a configurable local resolver daemon is the default
> - you could stop using Safari, although other apps using the default macOS networking stack may continue silently bypassing `/etc/hosts`
>
> Chrome has run some trials for this but [does not appear to have
> implemented it
> yet](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5948056459542528). Firefox has
> started implementing it [but doesn’t seem to have gotten too
> far.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634793)